# SSRS Rollup multiple levels and multiple rollups

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to set up a rollup for SSRS and am running into a bit of a problem. I have two hierarchies that I would like to display, but I can only figure out how to display 1.

Hierarchy 1

Division

Region

Territory

Hierarchy 2

Sum for all products

ProductA/ProductB/ProductC

Right now I have a report that lets me start with everything rolled up to Division and when I click on it it goes down to Region, etc just fine. The issue is that I want to be able to have another level of drilling down on the product hierarchy at every level of the other hierarchy.

For instance, when you are at a division level, say you wanted to see specifically how prodcut A was doing, so you would be able to click on an expand button and instead of getting the sum for all 3 products you would see that value broke out by each Product. You would also be able to do this when you are at a region level and a territory level.

What I am able to do right now is to add the product expansion into the other hierarchy, like:

Division

Region

Territory

product

Or

Division

product

Region

Territory

So when you get to the territory level, you can click again and expand to the 3 products, but that does not allow me to view a product break out at the region or division level.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thanks for you help SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am curious if this is what you mean, "So when you get to the territory level, you can click again and expand to the 3 products, but that does not allow me to view a product break out at the region or division level."  Do you mean collapse all the way down but not expand all at once?  I am taking you to mean 'can I expand on a dependency on the former'?

You can set this up if you are asking what I think you are asking.  I have done this in 2008 and 2012 but I am rusty if this works on 2005.  By putting a grouping dependency on the parent with it's visibility.   This lets SSRS know that ONLY that parent you are expanding should you expand on.  A simple example may help.  Say I have a simple data set:

```
declare @Table Table ( personID int identity, person varchar(8), orders int, level1 int, level2 int);

insert into @Table values ('Brett',10, 1,1),('John',20,1,1),('Peter',15,2,1),('Jessica',25, 2,1),('Eddie', 7, 3,1),('Jimi',50, 3,1),('Robert',5, 1,2)

select *
from @Table
```

1. I can define a table that then uses only two values thus far [person] and [Sum(orders)].
2. I then go to the 'Row Groups'>Right Click>Add Parent Group>'Group by:' level1 also add 'Add Group header'
3. Now you may create a cell value above the [orders] that is currently blank and change it to '[Sum(orders)]' this will now aggregate only the orders for their groupings.  But I realize this still does not address the question that is next
4. Go back to the 'Row Groups'>Right Click Details>'Group Properties'>'Visibility' on Left Pane>'When the report is initially run': Choose 'Hide'>Check 'Display can be toggled by this report item:' Choose 'level1'.  You have now bound your details pane to it's parent to collapse on demand for each parent object, NOT ALL AT ONCE.  Thus you can collapse by a level at a time.  But wait there is more....
5. I can go back to 'Row Groups'>RightClick 'level1'>Add Parent Group>'Group by: ' level2 and continue to do the heirarchy grouping for the parent adding a parent to it.

You can follow the instructions again for as many levels as you need.  You can do this with columns with a matrix as well.  The real power of these reports is in the visibility options and knowing what to show and what not to and how to organize data efficiently and present it in a way that an end user can get what they want when they need it.